# Anabelian geometry study materials?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ct.category-theory, galois-theory, anabelian-geometry

I want to study anabelian geometry, but unfortunately I'm having difficulties in finding some materials about it. If you could offer me some books/papers/articles I would be glad.

Comment: Szamuely, Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups, Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, vol. 117, Cambridge University Press, 2009.

Comment: The book mentioned by Felipe is available here:
http://math.uchicago.edu/~aanders/books/szamuely_-_galois_groups_and_fundamental_groups.pdf

Comment: I don't recommend that book. There are lots of errors (even concerning basic definitions) and inconsistencies.

Comment: (apologies for the over-long link but...) just discovered a recent master's thesis on mono-anabelian geometry: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiOhMiyz-7YAhWEulMKHeUiApIQFghIMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdspace.library.uu.nl%2Fbitstream%2Fhandle%2F1874%2F356898%2FScriptie_Anabelian_Geometry%2520%25281%2529.pdf%3Fsequence%3D2&usg=AOvVaw2cG5RKNpN036stEPNUrXdf

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is this very beautiful survey

Nakamura, Hiroaki; Tamagawa, Akio; Mochizuki, Shinichi

The Grothendieck conjecture on the fundamental groups of algebraic curves

http://www.math.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/~nakamura/zoo/rhino/NTM300.pdf

You could also have a look at

Szamuely, Tamás

Heidelberg Lectures on Fundamental Groups

http://www.renyi.hu/~szamuely/heid.pdf

Comment: That is quite a list of authors.

Answer (score 11):

Jakob Stix, Rational Points and Arithmetic of Fundamental Groups
Evidence for the Section Conjecture
Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics 2054, xx+pp.247, Springer 2012.  http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-3-642-30673-0

Comment: I'm sure this book will be the one to get, once it comes out. If you start with Szamuely as an introduction, you could then move on to this afterwards.

Comment: http://www.springer.com/mathematics/numbers/book/978-3-642-23904-5 Is this the same book?

Comment: No (it is a collection of conference talks), but this is also a good source.

Answer (score 7):

[This volume](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521808316), *Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups*, edited by Leila Schneps has a great collection of articles, as does [this volume](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521596424), *Geometric Galois Actions*, including a nice article by Florian Pop on "Glimpses of Grothendieck's anabelian geometry."

If you'd like videos, [here](http://www.newton.ac.uk/programmes/NAG/seminars/index.html) is a series of lectures on related topics, including a long series by Pop on anabelian geometry. At MSRI, you can find some [lectures from Fall 1999](http://www.msri.org/realvideo/index1.html), including one specifically about anabelian geometry.

Answer (score 4):

Florian Pop, Lectures on Anabelian phenomena in geometry and arithmetic [(pdf)](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~pop/Research/files-Res/AnabPhen_20Dec10.pdf)

Yuri Tschinkel, *Introduction to anabelian geometry*, talk at *[Symmetries and correspondences in number theory, geometry, algebra, physics: intra-disciplinary trends](https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/personal/ibf/files/sc3.html)*, Oxford 2014 ([slides pdf](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~tschinke/.talks/oxford14/oxford14.pdf))

Answer (score 3):

The article

Matsumoto, Makoto, Arithmetic fundamental groups and moduli of curves. School on Algebraic Geometry (Trieste, 1999), 355–383,  ICTP Lect. Notes, 1, Abdus Salam Int. Cent. Theoret. Phys., Trieste, 2000.

has a nice concrete discussion of fundamental groups.

Comment: http://users.ictp.it/~pub_off/lectures/lns001/Matsumoto/Matsumoto.pdf